# Object [object Array] has no method 'eq'

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get nth element from an array and getting this error: "Object [object Array] has no method 'eq'". Please take a look at the code and comments below:

```
var allsliders = []; //declare array

var eheight; //declare block height

$('.slider-wrapper').each(function(){
   eheight = $(this).find('.slider-body').height(); //find block height with (each)
   allsliders.push(eheight); //add block height to array
});  

var thisheight = allsliders.eq(0); //try to get first value from array

alert(thisheight); //test it out
```

So that's the problem, seems like `allsliders.eq(0)` method is not working. What's the possible way to get nth value from array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`allsliders` is a normal JavaSscript array, in this case an array of height numbers, not a jQuery object/collection:

```
var thisheight = allsliders[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped, I will accept your answer after timer.